Easy policy enforcing for 'user endpoint devices'
We are looking for a tool that allows us to easily enforce policies on 'user endpoint devices'.
At the time of writing, these are the only policy items to enforce:

Disk encryption (FileVault for macOS, AFAIK built-in for iOS).
Automatic OS updates.

On the following platforms:

Linux (preferably distro-agnostic, otherwise Debian only)
macOS
iOS (iPhone)

As I understand it, there are several methodologies, varying in complexity, each expanding on one another. In order:

MDM (Mobile Device Management)


"MDM software gives a company (often the IT department) the tools to set up, manage and secure mobile devices"




Source: https://www.kpn.com/zakelijk/blog/wat-is-emm-en-hoe-verhoudt-emm-zich-tot-mdm-mam-en-uem.htm


MAM (Mobile Application Management)


"MAM focuses on the applications on the phone and is about who is allowed to use what. These rights relate to the (company) apps and access to functionalities, but also to the settings, for example whether a mobile app is allowed to use GPS or a Wi-Fi hotspot."




Source: https://www.kpn.com/zakelijk/blog/wat-is-emm-en-hoe-verhoudt-emm-zich-tot-mdm-mam-en-uem.htm


EMM (Enterprise Mobility Management)


"In addition to hardware and applications, EMM focuses (even) more emphatically on data security. [...] EMM is an all-in-one solution that offers companies an environment for configuration, management, monitoring and reporting."




Source: https://www.kpn.com/zakelijk/blog/wat-is-emm-en-hoe-verhoudt-emm-zich-tot-mdm-mam-en-uem.htm


UEM (Unified Endpoint Management)


"[...] focuses on other internet-connected devices in addition to smartphones and tablets. Laptops, hand scanners from the warehouse and even Internet of Things sensors can be managed with this." Source: https://www.kpn.com/zakelijk/blog/wat-is-emm-en-hoe-verhoudt-emm-zich-tot-mdm-mam-en-uem.htm




Irrelevant, because our case is 'user endpoint devices' only




Source: https://www.hyper-ict.com/2024/10/22/uem-vs-xdr-key-differences/



Note: the term 'mobile' seems to be used interchangeably - by different tools - to refer to either only 'mobile' devices (such as smartphones), or all portable devices (such as laptops).
A quick search reveals that there are many tools that offer such functionality, such as:

Jamf
ManageEngine
Wazuh
NinjaOne

However, they are all far too extensive (and therefore too expensive for our - relatively simple - case). Also, each tool has its own lingo, which entangles us in a web of 'enterprise' software.
Again, our wishes are very basic, I described them at the top of this message. Reporting, monitoring, you name it: none of it is relevant in a general sense, only for policy violations.
The only -seemingly- suitable solution we found so far is 'Apple Business Manager'. However, as mentioned, we require a platform-agnostic solution.
